# c - incrementing array pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work. I'm java developer and new to c/c++
As far as i understood pointer of array is actually pointer of arrays first element, is that correct?

```
void test(char *tmp)
{
    test2(tmp);
    //*tmp++ = '1';
    //*tmp++ = '2';
    *tmp++ = '3';
    *tmp++ = '4';
    *tmp = 0;
}

void test2(char *tmp)
{
    *tmp++ = '1';
    *tmp++ = '2';
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char tmp[5];
    test(tmp);
    printf("%s", tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

only `34` gets printed. When i debug this code in function `test2` pointer of `tmp` is incremente by one but back in function `test` after test2 is called, pointer of `tmp` is back to its initial value.
If i just put all of the code in single function like this, it works:

```
void test(char *tmp)
{
    *tmp++ = '1';
    *tmp++ = '2';
    *tmp++ = '3';
    *tmp++ = '4';
    *tmp = 0;
}
```

Also what does the `*tmp = 0` on the last line do. I copied it from some other code. Without it there is some junk on the end of the array.

Comment: 1. Strings a null terminated (hence `*tmp = 0`). 2. Make the code readable by using `tmp[0] = ` etc.

Comment: @Ed Heal That works, and that is first thing i tried, but i don't want `test` to depend on `test2`. for example if i increment tmp in `test2` 3 times i want in test to just continue from forth. Is that possible?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight fixed

Comment: so if i have 4 elements do i need to make array with size 5 or not?

Comment: @pedja Yes, if you have four letters in your string, you need an array of five `char`s to fit null terminator as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameters are its local variables. Arguments are passed to functions by values that means that copies of the arguments are passed.

So in function `test2` there is used a copy of pointer `tmp` of function `test`. Any changes of a copy of an object do not influence on the object itself.

The call of test2 can be imagine the following way

```
void test(char *tmp)
{
//  test2(tmp);
    char *new_ptr = tmp;
    test2( new_ptr );
//  ...
}

void test2(/*char *tmp*/)
{
    char *tmp = new_ptr;
    *tmp++ = '1';
    *tmp++ = '2';
}
```

If you declared the parameter of `test2` as a reference to pointer then in this case the pointer itself could be changed. For example

```
void test(char *tmp)
{
    test2( &tmp );
    //     ^^^^
    //*tmp++ = '1';
    //*tmp++ = '2';
    *tmp++ = '3';
    *tmp++ = '4';
    *tmp = 0;
}

void test2(char **tmp)
//         ^^^^^^^^^^
{
    *( *tmp )++ = '1';
    *( *tmp )++ = '2';
}
```

As for arrays then an array used in expression with rare exceptions as for example using an array in operator `sizeof` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

So if for example you have an array of type `T`

```
T a[N];
```

then the following declaration

```
T *p = a;
```

is valid and the pointer is initialized by the address of the first element of the array `a`.

Another example

```
char *s = "Hello";
```

Here is string literal `"Hello"` is used in an expression as an initializer. The string literal that includes terminating zero `'\0'` has type `char[6]` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first character `'H'`.

In C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays. So the string literal `"Hello"` in C++ has type `const char[6]`.

So in C++ you have to write

```
const char *s = "Hello";
```

But in the both languages string literals are immutable.

Answer (score 4):

In function `test2`, pass-by-pointer means you can modify what `tmp` points to, but `test2` **does not modify the pointer itself**.

```
void test2(char *tmp)
{
    *tmp++ = '1';
    *tmp++ = '2';
}
```

So in the caller function `test`, after calling `test2` the pointer does not move forward by 2 positions as you would expect, instead `tmp` remains the same (which is pointing the the very first value of the array). So what actually happens is `test2` assign `1` and `2` for the first two elements, and then `test` overwrite those two values with `3` and `4`.

```
void test(char *tmp)
{
    test2(tmp);
    *tmp++ = '3';
    *tmp++ = '4';
    *tmp = 0;
}
```

> Also what does the *tmp = 0 on the last line do.

That's string terminator.

Comment: Ok i understand that now, but how can i make it work like this, without using `tmp[0]`, `tmp[1]` etc

Answer (score 2):

Incrementing the 'tmp' in test2() does not increment the 'tmp' in test().   After the test2() call returns, the '1' and '2' written by test2 are overwritten by '3' and '4'.

The zero is the '\0' c-style 'string' terminator.

Comment: So how can i do this without explicitly specifying array index? eg `tmp[0]`, `tmp[1]` etc.

Comment: One way would be to return the pointer from test2():  'char *test2(char *tmp)', ..... 'return tmp;' and call it it from temp as: 'tmp=test2(tmp);'

Answer (score 1):

The 0 is a nul terminator, the string ends with a 0 or nul byte so that functions like printf() know where the string ends, because - how long is a piece of string?

Since you're passing the pointer to test2() and test2() is incrementing the pointer - but not actually passing the altered/incremented pointer back to the calling function...as far as test() is concerned the pointer hasn't changed so subsequent alterations are overwriting previous changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *test2(char *tmp)
{
   *tmp++ = '1';
   *tmp++ = '2';

   return tmp;
}

void test(char *tmp)
{
    tmp = test2(tmp);

    //*tmp++ = '1';
    //*tmp++ = '2';
    *tmp++ = '3';
    *tmp++ = '4';
    *tmp = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char tmp[5];

    test(tmp);
    printf("%s", tmp);

    return 0;
}
```

Here test2 is returning the altered/incremented pointer to the caller, tess() will receive the updated char. Since you're adding the 0 or nul byte at teh end you need an array of at least 5 elements here.

the above code should work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that if you write all in 1 function you get 1234, but if you write 2 function passing always the same pointer the second one overwrite what the first has already done.

```
test:
tmp -> Point to [100]
call test2 giving [100] as parameter
write 3 in [100]
increment pointer from [100] to [101]
write 4 in [101]
increment pointer from [101] to [102]

test2:
tmp -> Point to [100]
write 1 in [100]
increment pointer from [100] to [101]
write 2 in [101]
increment pointer from [101] to [102]
```

Now I imagine you can see the error.